# Product attributes in navigation and in product tab

Tags: product, attributes, navigation, tabs

Sorry for the vague title. I will try and explain what I am looking for. I am designing a site for a garden nursery and have set up a product attribute group containing things such as 'Plant height', 'Spread', Soil Type' etc, the sort of things that you would normally filter plants with.

Some attributes are of more pertinence to customers in some categories of plants than others.

So an example of what I am trying to do is as follows: 'Spacing' is an important attribute to products in the 'Vegetables' category so I would need it in the layered navigation and the product description 'More Info' tab - so far so good.

But it's not as an important attribute for products in the 'Soft Fruit' category, so I wouldn't want to include it in layered navigation, but I would want to include it in the product description 'More Info' tab though.

Is there a way of doing this without having to create 6 separate 'Spacing' attributes for each main category?

TIA.